# Examples of projective modules which are not free modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

Are there some examples of projective modules which are not free modules? Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a non-principal ideal of a Dedekind domain. It is projective over the domain but is not free. More generally, projective modules feel like vector bundle, which is certainly not trivial in most cases.

Comment: For an explicit example of the general result described by Sanchez see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/322884/11619).

Answer (score 7):

Let $k$ be your favorite field and consider the ring $R = k \times k$.  Give $k$ the structure of an $R$-module via
$$(a, b)\cdot c = ac.$$
Then $k$ is a projective $R$-module because it is a direct summand of the free module $R$ (it's the left factor: $k \times 0$) but it is not isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $R$ so it is not free.

Comment: +1: In my opinion this is indeed the simplest example and should be given first. I also like to talk about Swan's Theorem and vector bundles in this context, and that perspective helps here: the geometric explanation is that a disconnected space yields very cheap examples of nontrivial vector bundles, namely those with different fiber dimensions over the connected components.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion of projective versus free modules in $\S 3.5.4$ of [my commutative algebra notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).  See also $\S 6$ on Swan's Theorem, especially $\S 6.4$ for a discussion and examples of modules which are *stably free* but not free.

Comment: +1: Nice notes! And a moral (unrelated) +1 for Galois connections...