# Prove that the $R$-module $I \bigoplus I$ is free on the generators $(2 ,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1-\sqrt{-5},2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, free-modules

Let $R=\mathbb Z [\sqrt{-5}]$, and $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$. Prove that the $R$-module $I \bigoplus I$ is free on the generators $(2, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1-\sqrt{-5},2)$.

Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: Can you show us your efforts on this problem? And perhaps at least correct your typos

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think a link might have gotten lost in the mix there?

Comment: Indeed, @BadamBaplan. I meant to link to [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321255/). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/298551/11619) is more of the same (generalizing the argument over any Dedekind domain, please read Alex Youcis's answer before mine).

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5}), b = (1 - \sqrt{-5}, 2)$ for convenience.

In order to show that $a,b$ generate $I \oplus I$, let's try to find linear combinations of $a,b$ that give generators of the submodules $I \oplus 0$ or $0 \oplus I$.  If you show that $a,b$ span these two submodules then you show they span $I \oplus I$.

For example, let's try to kill the first coordinate... calculate

$$(1 - \sqrt{-5}) a = (2 - 2\sqrt{-5}, 6)$$

$$2b = (2 - 2\sqrt{-5}, 4)$$

Hence $$(1 - \sqrt{-5})a -2b = (0,2)$$

Can you find linear combinations of $a,b$ that yield $(2,0)?$ And use this to finish showing that $a,b$ generate $I \oplus I$?

Well, once you've shown that $a,b$ span $I \oplus I$, you just need to show that they are linearly independent.

To that end, suppose that $r_1a + r_2b = 0$ with $r_1,r_2 \in R$.  You aim to show this implies $r_1= r_2 = 0$.  Looking at the equation in each coordinate of $I \oplus I$ gives you the two equations:

$$2r_1 + (1 - \sqrt{-5})r_2 = 0$$
$$(1 + \sqrt{-5})r_1 + 2r_2 = 0$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: A well designed argument!